# How to make an array of coins appear for game?

Tags: java, arrays, list, swing

How to make a list or an array of 10 coins appear on the game? It is the same coin image. I want my sprite (Mario) to pick up all 10 coins, but I want them next to each other } maybe I could manually type out the x locations.

Mainly I am not sure how to make the coins appear on the screen.

UPDATE: The coins appear when I manually type out each coin (exp. coins[0]=tool.kit..). It does not work with the for loop though.

```
public class Action extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    private Image man;
    int x=0, y=490, a=(int) (Math.random() * 450 + 1), b=500; // make a random num
    Image img;
    Image [] coins = new Image [10];


    public Action() {
        super.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
       img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("background.png");
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("realmario.png");
        man = ii.getImage();

        g.drawImage(img,0, 0, null);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.drawImage(man, x, y, this);
        g2d.drawImage(coins[1], a, b, this);

        for (int i = 0; i<coins.length; i++) {
            coins[i] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("coin.png");
        }

    }
```

Comment: If "It is the same coin image" why do you need an array of ten identical images `new Image [10]` ? Simply draw the same image 10 times in different location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place objects one linked to other you have to work with x-axis and adjust properly.

Eg. img have (3,7) pixels and first will be at (10,10). You need to grab x = 3 and made adjustments in loop.

1: img at 10,10 (initial)

2: img at 10+3,10

3: img at 10+3+3,10 ; etc

```
     //image dimension on x
     int image_x = 3;
     //initial placement on x,y
     int x=10,y=10;
     for(int i=0;i<coins.length; i++)
     { 
          //if same image is enough one coin
          g2d.drawImage(coin[7],x,y,this);
          x=x+image_x;
     }
```

Just check first the coordinates system.

Comment: Where would I put the image's url?

Comment: First think if you really need to get image from Url, or for your purposes if enough getting locally(local computer) as you did before. @coder example is self explanatory and show how to work also with url. coin is an image so it's just need to populated (either with a local image as you did or with one for web via URL).

Answer (score 0):

Draw the same image 10 times, each with different coordinates:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SwingTest extends JFrame {

    public SwingTest()  {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new ImagePanel());
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()-> new SwingTest());
    }
}

class ImagePanel extends JComponent {

    BufferedImage coin = getImage();
    private static final int GAP =2;

    public ImagePanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension( 300, 200));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int x=0, y= GAP;
        for (int i = 0; i <3 ; i++) {
            g.drawImage(coin,x,y, this);
            x= x+ GAP + coin.getWidth();
        }
    }

    public static BufferedImage getImage() {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.btcwmx.ru/admin/uploads/img/bitcoin-gold.png");
            return ImageIO.read(url);

        } catch ( IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}

        return null;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have not learned the try and catch method yet. Is there another way to get the image?

Comment: Getting the image from the web is needed so every one can run and test it (mcve). You can replace the image with your own image, as you did.